# Selecting a nested record to share show page of with selected users in action mailer via checkbox selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, actionmailer

So with the devise gem set up I have, my users can register as either a buyer account or a seller account.  If they're buyers, they can make nested inquiries for information to buy from sellers.  On the sellers index page, if I am a buyer and logged in as the current user, I want every inquiry that I've made to be displayed on a part of the page with the title of each inquiry displayed next to a radio button or as an option from a pull down menu for the buyer to select from, along with the inquiry ID hidden so I can use it in action mailer after I select it. I am guessing I need a form with a post request to select the inquiry I've done for the next step, so this is what I've been trying so far:

```
  <%= simple_form_for [@buyer, @inquiries], method: :post  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :inquiry.name, collection: @inquiries, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.text_field :inquiry_id, value: inquiry.id, type: "hidden"  %>
  <%= f.submit 'New user' %>
```

In my sellers index controller, for the buyer and inquiry I have

```
@buyer = current_user.buyer if current_user.buyer
@inquiries = @buyer.inquiries if current_user.buyer
```

However, I haven't been able to properly get my list of inquiries to show with a hidden ID either as a pull down menu of options or radio button options.

Afterwards, on the same seller index page, I have checkboxes on every individual seller partial card.  As a buyer, I want to be able to use action mailer to send every seller whose checkbox I clicked on an email inviting them to see a link to the show page of the inquiry that I've picked, all with the click of a button.  I haven't gotten close to getting this to work.  So far the checkbox I have on each seller partial so I can have their ID's hidden is this:

```
<%= check_box("seller", "id", {}, seller.id) %>
```

This is my inquiry mailer file:

```
class InquiryMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.inquiry_mailer.invite.subject
  #
  def invite(seller)
    # @greeting = "Hi"
    @buyer = current_user.buyer
    @inquiries = @buyer.inquiries
    @seller =  seller

    mail(to: @seller.email, subject: 'You have been invited to sell your!')

  end
end
```

And this is my invite.html.erb file:

```
<p>Hello, <%= @seller.email %>!</p>

<p>You have been invited to sell to <%=@buyer.name%>!</p>

<p>Their inquiry is titled <%= @inquiry.title %>, it can be found at<p>

<p><%= link_to 'See this inquiry!', buyer_inquiry_path(@buyer, @inquiry) %><p>
```

But I'm not sure if what I have so far is right and where to go from here to get my next steps to work.  I do not know how to transmit the inquiry ID to action mailer, nor do I know how to send the selected checkboxes properly either.  I'd be grateful for any advice on what steps I should take next to get my inquiries to show the proper way and how to send the inquiry that I pick to the sellers that I pick.  Thank you!

Comment: This is like 10 different questions rolled into one and would require an entire tutorial as an answer. Start with one question like `How do I select assoociations with a checkbox?` or `How do I send a emails to multiple users?`. If you search you can see that those questions have been answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give some idea

routes

```
resources :sellers do
  collection { post :notify }
end
```

form

```
<%= simple_form_for :inquiry, url: notify_sellers_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :ids, collection: @inquiries, as: :check_boxes, label: false%>
<%= f.submit %>
```

this will create checkbox for each inquiry (alternatively you can change it to a multi select)

on submit it will submit `inquiry[:ids]` to `notify` method in `SellersController`

There you can access ids `params[:inquiry][:ids]` and create notifications

```
def notify
  inquiry_ids = params[:inquiry][:ids]
  do stuff
  InquiryMailer.notify_seller(params[:inquiry][:ids])
  ...
end
```

---

For sellers

you can use above form and change `collection` to `collection: @sellers` or

```
<%= simple_form_for :seller, url: notify_sellers_path do |f| %>
  <% @sellers.each do |seller| %>
    <%= f.check_box :ids, { multiple: true }, seller.id, nil %>
    <%= seller.name %>
    ...
```

this will submit selected ids as `params[:seller][:ids]`

Comment: Ohh, wow, thanks man!  That really helped to clarify things into a more clearer picture for me.  So wait, since I can select which sellers on the sellers index to send an email to by checking or unchecking their checkboxes, how do I send the ID's of those sellers that I've selected to the controller and action mailer so that they could each receive an email?